# cant get SSL certificate for some reason

Tags: node.js, digital-ocean, back, certbot

I'm still new to this idea of deploying apps,

yet when I try to get the certificate (SSL/TLS) for using https in production,
I get this error:

```
Requesting a certificate for talmazet-elmalak.com

Certbot failed to authenticate some domains (authenticator: standalone). The Certificate Authority reported these problems:
  Domain: talmazet-elmalak.com
  Type:   dns
  Detail: DNS problem: SERVFAIL looking up A for talmazet-elmalak.com - the domain's nameservers may be malfunctioning; DNS problem: SERVFAIL looking up AAAA for talmazet-elmalak.com - the domain's nameservers may be malfunctioning

Hint: The Certificate Authority failed to download the challenge files from the temporary standalone webserver started by Certbot on port 80. Ensure that the listed domains point to this machine and that it can accept inbound connections from the internet.

Some challenges have failed.
Ask for help or search for solutions at https://community.letsencrypt.org. See the logfile /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log or re-run Certbot with -v for more details.
```

the command that I uses to get this issue is:

```
sudo certbot certonly --standalone --preferred-challenge http -d talmazet-elmalak.com
```

any ideas why this is happening?